# How to program factory reset switch in a small embedded device

Tags: embedded, interrupt, reset, interrupt-handling, rtos

I am building a small embedded device. I am using a reset switch, and when this is pressed for more than 5 seconds, the whole device should reset and clear all the data and go to factory reset state. 
I know what to clear when this event happens. What I want to know is how do I raise this event? I mean when switch is pressed, how do I design the system to know that 5 seconds have elapsed and I have to reset now. I need high level design with any timers and interrupts. Can some one please help me?

Comment: "high level design with... interrupts"   Eh?

Comment: In addition to all the interrupt-based methods, you can even do very simply by just occasional polling of the related pin.  Assuming you have a paced loop approach (as is common in many/[most?] embedded systems), you can simply check the status of the pin, and while the pin is in the 'key-pressed' state increment a counter, else zero it.  After an increment, if the counter exceeds the value corresponding to 5 seconds you can call your event.  (Eg. if you paced loop is set to cycle every 10ms, then your counter would reach 500 before you call the reset event).

Comment: If the device has one, wire it directly to a biassed RESET pin. If you need to press reset, there is no guarantee that the software will even function correctly. Locate the switch behind a cover that will take the user 5 seconds to open. If the device does not have a RESET pin, interrupt its power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the device. But few rough ideas:

Possibly the device manual may say about the number of interrupts per second that is produced by "holding down the switch" (switch down). If you have this value, you can easily calculate the 5 seconds.

If not, you would need to use timer too. Start the timer when you get the first interrupt of "switch down" and count up to 5 seconds.

Note that, You should also monitor for "switch up", that is, "release of switch". I hope there will be an interrupt for that too. (Possibly with different status value).
So you should break the above loop (you shouldn't do the reset) when you see this interrupt.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt-driven means low level, close to the hardware. An interrupt-driven solution, with for example a bare metal microcontroller, would look like this:

- Like when reading any other switch, sample the switch *n* number of times and filter out the signal bounce (and potential EMI).
- Start a hardware timer. Usually the on-chip timers are far too fast to count a whole 5 seconds, even when you set it to run as slow as possible. So you need to set the timer with a pre-scale value, picked so that one whole timer cycle equals a known time unit (like for example 10 milliseconds).
- Upon timer overflow, trigger an interrupt. Inside the interrupt, check that the switch is still pressed, then increase a counter. When the counter reaches a given value, execute the reset code. For example, if you get a timer overflow every 10 milliseconds, your counter should count up to 5000ms/10ms = 500.
- If the switch is released before the time is elapsed, reset the counter and stop the timer interrupt.
- How to reset the system is highly system-specific. You should put the system in a safe system, then overwrite your current settings by overwriting the NVM where settings is stored with some default factory settings stored elsewhere in NVM. Once that is done, you should force the processor to reset itself and reboot with the new settings in place.
- This means that you must have a system with electronically-erasable NVM. Depending on the size of the data, this NVM could either be data flash on-chip in a microcontroller, or some external memory circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a 5S or 30S timeout can be done using a GPIO on an interrupt.

If using an rtos, 
. Interrupt would wake a thread from sleep and disables itself,

. All the thread does is count the time the switch is pressed for (you scan the switch at regular intervals)

. **If the switch is pressed for desired time** set a global variable/setting in eeprom which will trigger the factory reset function

. **Else** enable the interrupt again and put the thread to sleep

. Also, use a de-bounce circuit to avoid issues.

Also define what do you mean by factory reset?

There are two kinds in general, both cases I will help using eeprom

1. Revert all configurations (Low cost, easier)

In this case, you partition the eeprom, have a working configuration and factory configuration. You copy over the factory configurations to the working partition and perform a software reset

2. Restore complete firmware (Costly, needs more testing)
   This is more tricky, but can be done with help of bootloaders that allow for flashing from eeprom/or sd card.

In this case the binary firmware blob will also be stored with the factory configuration, in the safe partition and will be used to flash controller flash and configurations.

All depends on the size/memory and cost. can be designed in many more ways, i am just laying out simplest examples.

Answer (score 0):

I created some products with a combined switch to. I did so by using a capacitator to initiate a reset pulse on the reset pin of the device (current and levels limit by some resistors and/or diodes). At start-up I monitor the state of the input pin connected to the switch. I simply wait until this pin goes height with a time-out of 5 seconds. In case of a time-out I reset my configuration to default.
[image]